# There is a Cell bothering me in a LibGDX Window

Tags: java, libgdx

I think I might have found an issue in LibGDX, but before opening an issue in their GitHub, I thought it would be better to discuss it here because maybe I am wrong.

This is what is happening to me:

I have a class named `Information` extending `Window`, where I show the information about the characters of my game. Since I need to update the labels dynamically, I thought it would be better to simply remove all the actors inside the `Window` each time I call `setVisible(false)`. It worked before. So this is my code:

```
public class Information extends Window {

private final static String TAG = Information.class.getName();
private Unit calledBy; //Variable to know who is calling


public Information (Skin skin) {

    //Setting the attributes
    super("Information", skin);
    this.setPosition(0, 0);
    this.setBounds(this.getX(), this.getY(), Constants.INFORMATION_WIDTH, Constants.INFORMATION_HEIGHT);
    this.setVisible(false);

}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    if (!visible){
        SnapshotArray<Actor> actors = this.getChildren();
        while (actors.size > 0){
            actors.get(0).remove();
        }
    } else {
        this.add(new Label("Name: " + getCalledBy().getName(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Attack: " + getCalledBy().getAttack(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Defense: " + getCalledBy().getDefense(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Health: " + getCalledBy().getHealth(), getSkin()));
    }
    super.setVisible(visible);
}
```

So, every time I call `setVisible`, I create or erase the actors. The thing is that the first time I call the method, it is working perfectly, but the second and successive times, it appears a `Cell` with no info besides the Name of the character.

I debugged the creation of the `Actors` and the deletion of the same and all seems to be working perfectly.

So I was about to open an issue in LibGDX's GitHub, but if someone knows why this is happening to me, I will prefer it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An empty window is a Table with children for the title bar, the content, and where the buttons go. You are removing those in your code and then adding your new labels to that content table that is no longer a child of the Window. The "correct" way to remove them would be to call getContentTable().clear();

Comment: Not exactly that way but you opened my eyes! Thank you very much! The correct method was simply `clearChildren()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So I am responding my own question in case someone needs it.

Thanks to Tenfour04 for his comment, since it helped me to find it.

The correct method to call was `clearChildren()`. This is my new code:

```
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    if (!visible){
        this.clearChildren();
    } else {
        this.add(new Label("Name: " + getCalledBy().getName(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Attack: " + getCalledBy().getAttack(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Defense: " + getCalledBy().getDefense(), getSkin()));
        this.row();
        this.add(new Label("Health: " + getCalledBy().getHealth(), getSkin()));
    }
    super.setVisible(visible);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.